# Create a square with n length, n height using strings

Tags: java, loops

Okay, I've been having issues with a small example which involves creating a square that is 13x13 individual "q"s in java. I understand that I need two loops in order to create both a column and a row, but I'm having issues creating the columns.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String q = "q";

    for(int i = 0; i<26; i++){
        for(int x = 0; x<13; x++){
            System.out.print(q);
            x++;
        }
        i++;
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: If you are incrementing them after every iteration, why not use a `for` loop instead? Also, what "issues" are you having?

Comment: Loops has nothing to do with printings. You will get the same output if you write `while(i<13*13) { System.out.print(q); i++; }`. You are missing `System.out.println()` after the inner loop.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun and `if(i%13==0)System.out.println();` is added in that loop then we solve the problem with a single loop! or, %13==12 might be best, put after the other prints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `System.out.println()` in the **outer** loop.

```
while(i<13){
    while(x<13){
        System.out.print(q);
        x++;
    }
    i++;
    System.out.println();
}
```

As the comments mentioned you would also be better off using a `for` loop for this.

Comment: I improved my code and the for loops did change it. However, it counts the new line as part of the loop, effectively giving half of the necessary qs. Is there a more efficient way to do this other than having to multiply the outer loops count by 2? That is to say to keep it i<13 instead of i<26?

Comment: Post your new code as what you just said didn't make much sense :s

Answer (score 1):

Before(or after, it just had be be between the close brace of the inner while, and the close brace of the outer while) the `i++` put in a `System.out.println();`

This will insert a line break after each row.